# Proper notation for errors='ignore' with index clause in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

working on another project today. It's going a lot better as I'm learning more, however I'm trying something new.

I have a dataframe that is performing excellently. However, I need it to drop rows of certain part numbers, as they are unrelated to my current project and I don't want to pick through them. There's about 112 in the sheet right now, so doing it manually would be incredibly time-consuming across the three sheets that get added to my SQL database. Right now I get the error

```
.....'KCB-0100T')' is an invalid key
```

Which I believe just means it doesn't exist in the sheet. It wont all the time, and isn't supposed to. What's the proper form for errors='ignore' when it comes to

```
indexdf = df[(df['Part Number'] == 'KSA-9132',....).index
```

A Little lower I have

```
df.drop(indexdf, errors='ignore',axis=0,inplace=True)
```

But it seems to throw the error before it even gets to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using a mask and isin:

```
# Add the part numbers you want to drop to this list
part_numbers_to_drop = ['KSA-9132', 'KCB-0100T', ...] 

# Use isin() to create a boolean mask 
mask = df['Part Number'].isin(part_numbers_to_drop)

# Drop the rows the mask 
df.drop(df[mask].index, inplace=True)
```